# Regex for a random set of chars and digits

Tags: java, regex, string, digits

I am looking for a regex that matches only when it sees a string that is randomly filled by digits and chars.

For example, `adfak332arg3` is allowed but `332352` and `fagaaah` are not allowed. `.*[^\\s]` looks fine for strings with only chars but how to fix it to accepts the desired strings and refuses the other two types?

Comment: Look at [Regex for password must be contain at least eight characters, at least one number and both lower and uppercase letters and special characters](//stackoverflow.com/q/19605150), this will help you create the regex.

Answer (score 3):

Use a positive lookahead `(?=)` to ensure that the string contains required characters.

```
^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]+$
```

Test this regex pattern [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/ebIbyJ/1).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this regex

```
"[\\d\\w]*\\d\\w[\\d\\w]*|[\\d\\w]*\\w\\d[\\d\\w]*"
```

Comment: Care to make some more explanation?

Comment: [\\d\\w]* Means zero or more instances of a sequence of alternating digits and word characters (Common characters).    \\d\\w Means one digit and one word character (In that order)

Comment: @CoffeehouseCoder what i mean is that why there are a fix number of duplications of `\\d\\w` with and without `[]`

Comment: it matches one digit / char or char / digit combination with any number of chars or digits in before and afer

Answer (score 0):

If you need just a mixed string of characters A-Z, a-z and 0-9 you can use:

```
^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])$
```

If you want to force the string to have a minimum number of characters in your string you can use (e.g. minimum 8 in the string):

```
^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9]).{8,}$
```

If you want to have a string length from *min-length* to *max-length* then use (e.g. string of at least 5 characters and max 20 characters):

```
^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9]).{5,20}$
```

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that an input contains digits as well as characters, you could use this regex:

```
^(?:[A-Za-z]+\\d+|\\d+[A-Za-z]+)[A-Za-z\\d]*$
```

The regex ensures that the input **contains at least a number and a character, and allows only numbers or characters** (no special characters etc.)

- `(?:[A-Za-z]+\d+|\d+[A-Za-z]+)` ensures that it starts with one or more characters followed by digits or alternatively `|\d+[A-Za-z]+` one or more digits followed by one or more characters
- `[A-Za-z\d]*` allows any number of characters or digits after the previous check
- `^` and `$` to match starting and ending anchor

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Cxym7r/1/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: well, a string is allowed only and if only it contains both digits and chars.

Comment: @lonesome yes that is what the above regex matches

Answer (score 0):

Try this Regex.

[A-z][0-9]|[0-9][A-z]